# How to use BLE to uniquely identify a device

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, hardware, identifier

I have an **hardware capable of transmitting BLE signals** and I would like to uniquely identify it from a mobile application.

Is this possible?

- Does each BLE chip come with a unique identifier?
- If so can the identifier be changed?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can uniquely identify it from a mobile application.

- Does each BLE chip come with a unique identifier?

  Most probably yes, but in some cases it may not, But there will be some unique identity for the device.
- If so can the identifier be changed?

  I think it depends on the chip and if you want you can change using some interface. But sure it will not automatically change and cant be change by a common user.
  For your reference [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

And one of the device which using the BLE is [beacons](http://estimote.com/)

And [here](http://evothings.com/doc/examples/ble-scan.html) is a sample application you can try

Comment: Thank you. Would you have some more documentation on how to setup a unique identifier in a BLE chip?

Comment: Sorry i dot know much more about the hardware part, Please use some other stack blog to get helped.